# Not able to write Test cases for Spring Boot application with actual DB connection from Service to DAO

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Can anyone let me know, how to write JUnit test cases for Spring Boot application with actual DB connection?

I mean to say, when we right click on @Test class in src/test/java, and click on Run as JUnit Test, we need to Autowire all the beans of Service and DAO which we had developed in src/main/java and control should flow from @Test class to Service and Service to DAO and queries should be executed using @PersistenceContext Entitymanager and return successfully with the desired results.

The stack specifications

Spring Boot 1.5.10
JPA

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can first refer to the documentation of the [SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

Spring Boot testing instruments allow you to 'slice' application into pieces, test it separately and test application as a whole. If you want to concentrate on database testing - consider using @DataJpaTest.

As for databases: it is a more common case to use in-memory databases like H2 during testing. But, if you want to test against the real databases, take a look at [TestContainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java) or it's particular implementation ([test container spring boot](https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot))